# How to change text in nav menu when user change width of screen? Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

How to change text in nav menu when user change width of screen?

I try:

```
            <li>
                <p class="navbar-text visible-lg underline">Contacts & Delivery</p>
                <p class="navbar-text hidden-lg underline">Contacts</p>
            </li>
```

It's work, but text start text moves up. I can fix it using tag 'a' instead 'p', but i don't wont link in nav menu.

Comment: I don't understand it fully but check using firebug to the styles added from bootstrap. The p tags have a margin specified by default

Comment: Unless you're on to something I don't know, using `p` instead of `a` tags in either the navbar or nav in Bootstrap causes that nav item to break, as in it's no longer clickable. Why are you using paragraph tags instead of anchor tags, exactly?

Comment: @MattD, please see http://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar-text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your problem well, it should be fixed when appending the following CSS code after Bootstrap's CSS:

```
.navbar-text { margin-left: 15px; margin-right: 15px; }
```

When you are using Less:

```
.navbar-text {
  margin-left: @navbar-padding-horizontal;
  margin-right: @navbar-padding-horizontal;
}
```

Also see: https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15239

**update**
From https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/pull/15239 follows that you should not use the `.navbar-text` inside a `li` or any other tag. An alternative for the above solution, which keep the `.navbar-text` as intended, will be to create a new class for texts inside the `li`  's

**less**

```
.navbar-nav-text {
  &:extend(.nav > li > a);
  &:extend(.navbar-nav > li > a);
  p& {
    margin: 0;
  }
}
.navbar-default {
    .navbar-nav-text {
        color: @navbar-default-color;
    }
}
.navbar-inverse {
    .navbar-nav-text {
        color: @navbar-inverse-color;
    }
}
```

or **css**

```
.navbar-nav-text {
  position: relative;
  display: block;
  padding: 10px 15px;
  line-height: 20px;
}
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .navbar-nav-text {
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
  }
}

p.navbar-nav-text {
  margin: 0;
}
.navbar-default .navbar-nav-text {
  color: #777777;
}
.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav-text {
  color: #9d9d9d;
}
```